# Install sandbox solution to SPWeb

Tags: sandbox-solution

I need to install a sandboxed solution to my site (SPWeb). However I am not a site collection administrator, and therefore cannot access the solution gallery that exists at the site collection level. I am a site (SPWeb) administrator though. How can I deploy my solution on the site (SPWeb) that I am admin of? Or do I have to ask the site collection admin to upload my .wsp to the site solution gallery for me?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to ask a Site Collection Admin to upload it for you if you don't have the right permission.

> A sandboxed solution is installed by a site collection administrator
>   to the site collection's solution gallery. This gallery also shows the
>   current resource usage, average resource usage over the past two
>   weeks, and the status of each sandboxed solution.

[Sandboxed solutions overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721992.aspx#administer)

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much (and I also saw that documentation). I guess it can't be done using powershell either, since I can't access the server anyway. Btw, do you know of any way how I can tell what the URL is of the site collection?

Comment: A site-collection url will either look like:
"_http://www.mysite.com"    
OR   
"_http://www.mysite.com/sites/mysitecollection" (without _)  
and "sites" can be replaced by other values...

Comment: The sitecollection usually starts either at the root / or one level below sites, but can be setup in Central Administration to start at any level.